# Converting GeoTIFF to 3D shapefile?

Tags: raster, shapefile, convert, 3d

I have a GeoTIFF in which the data represents flood heights. I want to create a 3D vector that shows the flood heights from the GeoTIFF.

Please suggest any methodologies/tools if this is possible.

Comment: @MrXsquared I am looking for a way to achieve this, it could be with any software.

Comment: sounds like you need raster to vector conversion https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/raster_to_vector.html

Comment: @JakobMiksch Already tried this, this can only gives a 2D shapefile.

Comment: I actually do not really know what "3D shapefile" is, but I guess [drape](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#drape-set-z-value-from-raster) could help you